# Why a python process in linux shuttdown my Pc and not in Windows?

Tags: python, process, linux-kernel, out-of-memory, ram

PC features:

OS: Debian 10 x64
Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
motherboard: Rogstrix b450-f
Ram: 16gb 
GPU: ZotaGaming 2070 super.

I try to run a program,**ANFIS** whit data set **IRIS**.
but from one moment to another, the processor stops or something similar, also the peripherals stop working, and the ram warning LED turns on.

I don't understand why, since in **Windows this doesn't happen to me.** At first I thought it was because run on **anaconda virtual environment** in **Windows**, however in **Linux** even with **Dockers**, the same problem still occurs to me.

Comment: There has to be a huge amount of potential factors, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the processor voltage, the configuration of the bios. Change 0.02v to 0.01v,In offset mode.

If you keep crashing, Reduce the chipset clock frequency